# How to leave newline unmodified while incrementing/decrementing alphabet characters?

Tags: java

I have a string as follows:

```
String sentence = "I have 20 apples.\n" +
                   "Kevin has 15 apples.\n" +
                   "Peter has nothing."
```

I want to increment every alphabet characters by 2 leaving other characters(whitespace, special characters, newline etc) unmodified.

Here is a program I wrote.

```
public static void incrementCharacters(String sentence) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sentence));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
        for(int i =0; i < line.length(); i++){
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){
                if(Character.isUpperCase(ch){
                    str.append(Character.toUpperCase((char)(ch + 2)));

                } else {
                    str.append(Character.toLowerCase((char)(ch + 2));           
                }

            } else {
               str.append(ch);
            }

        }

    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

But the output I get is "I have 20 apples.Mgxkp jcu 15 crrngu.Rgvgt icu pqvjkpi." with newline omitted.
How can I modify this program so that I have new line included for my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your use of `BufferedReader` or `Character.toUpperCase()`.  Just iterate through your string, and increment each character, that is a letter, by 2 to a `StringBuilder` then return that as the result.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sentence = "I have 20 apples.\n" +
                   "My friend has 15 apples.\n" +
                   "My cousin has nothing.";

        System.out.println(incrementCharacters(sentence));           

    }

    public static String incrementCharacters(String sentence) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(Character.isLetter(c) ? (char)(c + 2) : (char)c);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
K jcxg 20 crrngu.
O{ htkgpf jcu 15 crrngu.
O{ eqwukp jcu pqvjkpi.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `BufferedReader` which will remove line break when you call `readLine`.

You don't need `BufferedReader`, just iterate every char in `sentence`.

```
public static void incrementCharacters(String sentence) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
            str.append((char) (ch + 2));
        } else {
            str.append(ch);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can provide a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readline()` removes the newline characters. Since you know this happens on each iteration of the `while` loop, one solution is to insert the newline characters back into the output. You can easily do this after the inner `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling readLine().  Lines are delimited by \n so they are not included in the results of readLine().  Just do this

```
public static void incrementCharacters(String sentence) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sentence));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
        for(int i =0; i < line.length(); i++){
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){
                if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                    str.append(Character.toUpperCase((char)(ch + 2)));
                } else {
                    str.append(Character.toLowerCase((char)(ch + 2)));
                }
            } else {
                str.append(ch);
            }
        }
        str.append("\n"); // just add this
    }

    System.out.println(str);
}
```